# Hibernate txProxyTemplate and declaring transactions

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions

I have a bean that extends this txProxyTemplate and inside it, this method orderUpdateOverseer calls getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(someObject);

```
private void orderUpdateOverseer(OrderReturnState orderReturnState) throws ReturnsOrderUpdateException
```

I noticed that hibernate flushes the updates to the database only when I fully exit the bean that extens txProxyTemplate instead of doing that on exit of the method orderUpdateOverseer that I have declared to be in a new transaction. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

```
<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="hibernateTransactionMgr" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="getAmos*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="orderUpdateOverseer">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>
            <prop key="recordProcessOverseer">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="store*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="merge*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="split*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="receive*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spring transaction aspects are proxy-based](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained), therefore they are not applied to `private` methods as well as to calls of a method from another method of the same object.

If you need to call a method of the same object inside a new transaction, the simpliest way to do it is to use [programmatic transaction management (`TransactionTemplate`)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic).